# notification doesn't start activity

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an alarmservice which is an intentservice to set alarms and an onAlarmReceiver broadcast receiver that starts a notification. in my notification I set an intent to the main page of my app. when people upgrade my app, notification still works fine but it SOMETIMES not always redirects them to the last page which was open last time. It seems like pending intent is not started at all. Does it mean that there is an exception that causes app to load previous state? Or app was killed? apparently it's going back to the previous state. I even changed the activity of pending intent to something else and there is still such a problem.... How can I see what happens in the device?
this is how I call notification broadcast:

```
AlarmManager mgrAlarm= (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ctxt, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, ++alarmCounter, intentAlarm, 0);
mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

and this is my onAlarmReceiver

```
Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, welcomeIntent,   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name="pvApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity  
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".unistall"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences" android:label="@string/set_preferences" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Questionnaire" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AfterSubmission"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".UserDemographics"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Instructions"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".unistall"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PersonalityTest"></activity>   
    <activity android:name=".finalQuestions"></activity>                
    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver"  android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"  ></receiver>        
    <receiver android:name=".OnNetworkReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
             <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>            
    </receiver> 
    <service android:name=".updaterService"    />
    <service android:name=".alarmService"   />
<receiver android:name=".onAppReplaced">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package"/>           
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` goes on the `Intent`, not the `PendingIntent` wrapper.